# No module named 'wptools' even after pip install wptools

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook and tried to import wptools. ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'wptools' popped up, so I tried

```
pip install wptools
```

It gave me a really long error message including:

- Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10
- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1
- WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Prgram Files\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I thought this package comes pre-installed with anaconda. What is the issue with my jupyter notebook environment and How can I fix this issue? Please advise.

Comment: try pip3 install wptools

Comment: It says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"